# I created a class in Python, but am unable to call the method

Tags: python, class, oop

**What I'm trying to accomplish** - I wrote this code so that I can use the bootstrapping method from statistics to create a 95% confidence interval of the mean. I want to pass a list of integers to the "CI" method and then have the method return the string at the end.

**Problem** - The code doesn't generate any output when I run it. Please help!

**Here is the code:**

```
class bootstrapping(object):

    def __init__(self,hours=[]):
        self.hours = hours

    def CI(self,hours):
        from random import randint
        x=0
        for numbers in range(0,1000):
            bootstraplist = []
            while x >= 0:
                bootstraplist.append(hours[randint(0,6)])
            if x <= 5:
                x += 1
                continue
            else:
                break
        listofmeans.append(sum(bootstraplist) / len(bootstraplist))
        import numpy
        s = numpy.std(listofmeans)
        z = 1.96

        lower_confidence = (sum(listofmeans) / len(listofmeans)) - z*s
        upper_confidence = (sum(listofmeans) / len(listofmeans)) + z*s

        return "Lower confidence:",lower_confidence,"Upper confidence:",upper_confidence
```

[Snapshot of the error I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYkyk.jpg)

Comment: How exactly are you calling it? Can you show the code that actually calls that method?

Comment: `while x >= 0:` will create an infinite loop if you do not decrease `x` inside the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, `listofmeans` is never initially declared in your method. Where is your declaration for that?

Comment: I tried to call it like this: bs.bootstrapping([1,2,3,4,5]) and then bs.CI().

Comment: What is `bs` in your code? Shouldn't it be `bs=bootstrapping([1,2,3,4,5]) bs.CI([1,2,3,4,5])`? Btw. if you have `self.hours = hours` in `__init__` you can use `self.hours` instead of `hours` in `CI`method and that way you can define `CI` without parameters.

Comment: @running.t I intended 'bs' to be the instance of the bootstrapping class

Comment: So, as I wrote before, you should make `bs` an instance of bootsrapping `bs=bootstrapping([1,2,3,4,5])`

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Python, so please excuse me. When I type "self" in the argument, it doesn't turn green like in the examples. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @running.t Sorry, I made a typo. bs=bootstrapping([1,2,3,4,5]) was what I had typed to create the instance.

Comment: The `*` means it hasn't returned, as @elethan said, you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
while x >= 0:
    bootstraplist.append(hours[randint(0,6)])
```

this is a infinite loop, as should know the indentation level is what create block of code in python, so as the `if` bellow have the same level as the `while`, the `if` is outside the `while` block.

I am not sure what your objective is there, but the more easy way to repeat a code a fixed number of time is with a for-loop over a range(n) where n its the number time to repeat the action. In your case that can be something like this

```
for _ in range(5):
    bootstraplist.append(hours[randint(0,6)])
```

( the use of `_` is a convention for a variable for which we don't care its value and/or we don't use)

or you could use list comprehension to create the list directly

```
bootstraplist = [hours[randint(0,6)] for _ in range(5) ]
```

also, by the way you use it looks like instead of randint, [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) is the better option

```
bootstraplist = [choice(hours) for _ in range(5) ]
```

Other things, is good practice to put all your imports as the first thing you do in your code.

Taking that in consideration along with the comment, perhaps this is what you want?

```
import numpy
from random import choice

class bootstrapping(object):

    def __init__(self,hours=[]):
        self.hours = hours

    def CI(self):
        listofmeans = []
        for numbers in range(0,1000):
            bootstraplist = [ choice(self.hours) for _ in range(5) ]    
            listofmeans.append(sum(bootstraplist) / len(bootstraplist))

        s = numpy.std(listofmeans)
        z = 1.96

        lower_confidence = (sum(listofmeans) / len(listofmeans)) - z*s
        upper_confidence = (sum(listofmeans) / len(listofmeans)) + z*s

        return "Lower confidence:",lower_confidence,"Upper confidence:",upper_confidence
```

test

```
>>> test=bootstrapping(range(1,6))
>>> test.CI()
('Lower confidence:', 1.7676140938359097, 'Upper confidence:', 4.2427859061640962)
>>>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is exactly what I needed